# Send form values into JSON and php api using QT

Tags: php, qt, api

I have written an API that I want to accept form values for the HTTP header POST.

Using PHP, I can make use of the API link using the following code:

```
$data = array(
    "authorid" => $_POST['author'],
    "filmid" => $_POST['film'],
    "content" => "".$_POST['content']."",
    "score" => $_POST['score']
);

$post = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('http://www.website.co.uk//v1/review/'); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($post))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

I am however using the API in a QT application.

What is the best way to store the form values and when they are submitted, send the HTTP header request POST along with the array of data to the link I gave above.

Got no idea how to achieve this!

Thanks,
Luke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of questions like this here, just browse through them and find what is closest to your situation. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564814/qt5-posting-data-to-server-using-qurl-qnetworkrequest) shows how to do a POST request. [Here](https://gist.github.com/rla/3163550) is another one with JSON serializiation, just google "qt post qnetworkrequest json" and there should be tons of answers.

Comment: Ok thanks, I wasn't sure what I was looking for in regards to google keywords. Ideal!

Comment: Well i hope the two links also make a base for what you need to create the code;) How about an accept? :D